# Getting to grips with array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the basic question.

I am trying to simplify some code and I have been looked over the array.map instead of using for loops to iterate through my arrays an using array.push.  I managed to get the basics to work but am struggling to apply an where condition.  Here is my current code as is:

```js
var masterArray = [{
    "masterName": "One",
    "minorArray": []
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Two",
    "minorArray": ["A", "B", "C"]
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Three",
    "minorArray": ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"]
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Four",
    "minorArray": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },


];
var minorArray = [];

var setMinorArray = function(value) {
  var selectedName = value;

  for (var i = 0; i < masterArray.length; i++) {
    if (masterArray[i].masterName == selectedName) {
      minorArray = [];
      minorArray = masterArray[i].minorArray;
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(minorArray);
};

setMinorArray("Three");
```

I have to target IE11 users so I cannot use arrow functions.  Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You can't apply a `where` condition with `map()`.

Comment: you want [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: You can use `array.find()` to find the element you want.

Comment: @DanO Actually he wants `find()` because he breaks out of the loop after finding the first match.

Comment: `Array.filter()` is an arguably better fit for the description of the problem ("where condition" plus "array push"), but I agree that `Array.find()` is a better fit for this particular code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is the wrong tool for the job - you're trying to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) an element in the array:

```js
var masterArray = [{
    "masterName": "One",
    "minorArray": []
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Two",
    "minorArray": ["A", "B", "C"]
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Three",
    "minorArray": ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"]
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Four",
    "minorArray": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },


];
var setMinorArray = function(value) {
  var minorArray = masterArray.find(x => x.masterName === value).minorArray;

  console.log(minorArray);
};

setMinorArray("Three");
```

Comment: I tried this before but unfortunately found that IE11 does not support .find()

Comment: ok, I used this and found a polyfil for IE 11 users.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would not be an appropriate use of `map()`. It's used when you want to create a new array that has the results of processing every element of the original array. Your loop checks a condition before processing the element, and then exits the loop after processing that element.

For that, you should use `find()`. It returns the first element that matches a condition function.

```js
var masterArray = [{
    "masterName": "One",
    "minorArray": []
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Two",
    "minorArray": ["A", "B", "C"]
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Three",
    "minorArray": ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"]
  },
  {
    "masterName": "Four",
    "minorArray": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
];
var minorArray = [];

var setMinorArray = function(value) {
  var found = masterArray.find(({masterName}) => masterName == value);
  if (found) {
    minorArray = found.minorArray;
  }
  console.log(minorArray);
};

setMinorArray("Three");
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have provided correct answers, `Array.map` is not the tool for the job but if you're really set to use it first-hand, here's how you can (ab)use it creatively:

```js
const masterArray2 = [
  { masterName: 'One', minorArray: [] },
  { masterName: 'Two', minorArray: ['A', 'B', 'C'] },
  { masterName: 'Three', minorArray: ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y'] },
  { masterName: 'Four', minorArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
]

const selectedValues = ['Three', 'Two']

const minorArray = masterArray2
  .map(({ masterName, minorArray: ma }) => selectedValues.includes(masterName) ? ma : [] )
  .join(',')
  .split(',')
  .filter(n => !!n)

console.info({ minorArray }) // will be ["A", "B", "C", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The array can be converted to key value lookup object, and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Browser_compatibility) is available since IE 9 :

```js
var masterArray = [ { "masterName": "One"  , "minorArray": [] },
                    { "masterName": "Two"  , "minorArray": ["A", "B", "C"] },
                    { "masterName": "Three", "minorArray": ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"] },
                    { "masterName": "Four" , "minorArray": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] } ];

var obj = masterArray.reduce(function(o, v) { 
                               return (o[v.masterName] = v.minorArray, o); }, {});

console.log( obj["Three"] );
```